# Pulling an apk of paid app from the device

Tags: android, apk, adb, pull

I'm pulling the apk file from an android device by the following command:

```
./adb pull /data/app/com.example.tracker-1.apk
```

This works fine. This works for the free apps in the google play store.
If I try to pull the .apk file of the paid app from the device like below,

```
 ./adb pull /mnt/asec/net.stfj.spelltower-1/pkg.apk
```

I get the following message

```
   failed to copy '/mnt/asec/net.stfj.spelltower-1/pkg.apk' to './pkg.apk': Permission denied
```

Is there a way I can pull this apk file?

Comment: is your device rooted? Also this is offtopic for SO. http://android.stackexchange.com would be more appropriate.

Comment: nope its not rooted. is there anyother way or cmds other than rooting?

Comment: I don't think so. You don't have read permission on the directory you are trying to access. Without root there should not be a way for you to gain permission to it. You could try using one of the "Backup your apps" applications on the market, but I doubt those will be able to pull the apk out of that folder if you can't with adb.

Comment: What would I do if I root the device? Will the commands be the same? Or do I need to root my adb as well?

Comment: If you are rooted then you could use chmod to give the permissions that you need to read the file. If you go that route you should use chmod to re-apply the standard permissions when you are done.

Comment: So  can I use the same ./adb pull <apk path> to get the file?

Comment: once you granded read permission you should be able to yes.

Answer (score 2):

On a non-rooted device, you can't pull files from the /mnt/asec protected filesystem. This foward-locked method was created to avoid copy and distribution paid apps.

If you are interested in getting some data about the app, your could pull the resources and Manifest files from the APK using the appInfo.publicSourceDir path which points usually to:

```
/mnt/asec/com.example.tracker-1/**res.zip**
```

This file includes all the app resources and Manifest file, but excludes the classes.dex app code.